# CRUD on SharePoint list with angular $resource

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

In my Service I have a function to get the Id and Title of all items inside a SharePoint list, this looks like this:

```
this.getList = function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var restQueryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items?$select=Id,Title";
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: restQueryUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            deferred.reject(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });
    return deferred;
};
```

But I've been reading about [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), and it seems like you have a lot more control over your data, it's more isolated, but I can't find any useful help when using this with SharePoint.

In the 'credit card' example they define a class like this:

```
var CreditCard = $resource('/user/:userId/card/:cardId',
  {userId:123, cardId:'@id'}, {
  charge: {method:'POST', params:{charge:true}}
});
```

If I have a SharePoint list with the fields 'Id','Title' and 'Description', called 'Items', how can I define a Item class, like the above example does for the credit card, so that I can 'query' all items from that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a full solution you need to work around with the following code and i referring some links for your convenience.

Here [Link](https://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/17/getting-list-data-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-and-angular-js/) nice and easy articleexplaining how to get List Data in SharePoint 2013 using Rest api and AngularJS .

This [Link](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/restful-crud-with-angularjs/) explaining how to use REST API to Host Web with AngularJS Services.

$resource

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]);
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('ResourceController',function($scope, Entry) {
  var entry = Entry.get({ id: $scope.id }, function() {
console.log(entry);
  }); // get() returns a single entry

  var entries = Entry.query(function() {
console.log(entries);
  }); //query() returns all the entries

  $scope.entry = new Entry(); //You can instantiate resource class

  $scope.entry.data = 'some data';

  Entry.save($scope.entry, function() {
//data saved. do something here.
  }); //saves an entry. Assuming $scope.entry is the Entry object  
});
```

The result of the function call is a resource class object which has the following methods by default:

```
get()
query()
save()
remove()
delete()
```

Here you need to incorporate the following SharePoint rest API with ajax

```
function get(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

Method to save into SharePoint list

```
function save(url, data) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

Method to update a item in SharePoint list

```
function update(url, oldItem, newItem) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-Http-Method": "PATCH",
        "If-Match": oldItem.__metadata.etag
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(newItem),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

Method to delete a item in SharePoint list

```
function delete(url, oldItem) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "If-Match": oldItem.__metadata.etag
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}
```

Sample code to list a SharePoint list

```
var employeesApp = angular.module(‘myApp’, []);
employeesApp.controller(’employeeCtrl’, function ($scope, $http) {
$http(
    {
        method: “GET”,
        url: “/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(‘Employees’)/items”,
        headers: { “Accept”: “application/json;odata=verbose” }
    }
    ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.employees = data.d.results;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(‘Error’);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great and all, but where, and how do I define the 'Entry'? As I understand it, the entry should be connected to my sharepoint list, so how do I set the entry resource to that list?